# KeyDown event doesnt work

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I would need that (on a WinForm) if the key <kbd>A</kbd> is pressed, an event is triggered.
I got this code from the MSDN site:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode != Keys.A)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Key 'a' was pressed.");
     }
}
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work for me, there is no error message, but if I am on the form and press the key <kbd>A</kbd> there is no event triggered. I tried to use breakpoints, but it never enters the `if`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Well, for one, you have `!=`, which means is looking for a key that's *not* `Keys.A`. Also, you probably still have to add this function to the form's keydown event (you can use the designer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `True`. This property gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

Also note that there is a mistake in your code; according to your message you need to verify if `e.KeyCode == Keys.A`.

Comment: OK, atleast there is SOME form of response. But not if I press the key A. Instead, if i press SPACE the MessageBox is shown.

Comment: Thats because your if statement says to do that. If `e.KeyCode DOES NOT EQUAL Keys.A`...

Comment: @KDecker Oh my god, I am stupid. Thanks for the response!